# Wrong record being updated in dataset

Tags: c#, dataset

I get my value without issue. The problem is, it always updates the first record in the datatable and of my current record with the same value.

My Code:

```
  public partial class Form2 : Form
  {
    public int InventoryId = 0;
    private DataRow CurrentRow;

    public Form2()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SaveItem_Click()
    {
      this.Validate();
      this.inventoryBindingSource.EndEdit();
      this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.garysInventoryDataSet);
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.inventoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.garysInventoryDataSet.Inventory);

      CurrentRow = (from x in garysInventoryDataSet.Inventory
        where x.InventoryId == InventoryId
        select x).FirstOrDefault();

      if (CurrentRow == null)
      {
        MessageBox.Show("Inventory Item Not Found.");
      }

      yearToDateQuantityTextBox.Text = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"].ToString();
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"]) + 1;
      yearToDateQuantityTextBox.Text = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"].ToString();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"] = Convert.ToInt32(CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"]) - 1;
      yearToDateQuantityTextBox.Text = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"].ToString();
    }

    private void Form2_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
      SaveItem_Click();
    }
  }
```

I can't seem to find out why it is also updating the first record. I'm getting the right value in CurrentRow but when it saves it, I am getting my first row overwritten and the the current row also.

Comment: Unrelated: `yearToDateQuantityTextBox.Text = CurrentRow["YearToDateQuantity"].ToString();` will throw NRE if CurrentRow is null. Since you check it before, it seems somewhat possible, so you might want to take precautions for that.

Comment: Please add `Validate()` implementation.

Comment: How, when and where do you update the referecne of "CurrentRow" and the value of "InventoryId" ?

Comment: @Fildor Ty for your input. I am updating it at SaveItem_Click(); At least, that is my intent.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't realize it but my textbox was still partially bound. I deleted the textbox and recreated it and it started working correctly.